# Word macro for changing color for negative numbers in a specific column depending on value in a different column

Tags: vba, ms-word

Thanks in advance for any reply.
I am working on presentation of some reports. The periodical reports are imported from a different software into Word template. For all tables and for each row I would like to change the color of the negative numbers in column 14 only if there is a certain text in column 3.
Unfortunately I have to use a Word template to do this. It seems that a macro is my only option so I have tried to Frankenstein something from different macros I found online:

```
Dim varColumn As Column
Dim clColumn As Column
Dim cCell As Variant

    Set clColumn = Selection.Columns(3)
    Set varColumn = Selection.Columns(14)

With clColumn
With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .text = "value"
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell, Count:=11
        End If
            If cCell < 0 Then
            Selection.Font.color = wdColorRed
        End If
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question ? What does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the macro needs lines to repeat the search. See the two lines added before Loop.

```
With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'Starts at the beginning, to search all tables.
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "value"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True And _
            .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 3 Then 'Confirms it's in the 3rd column.
            .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell, Count:=11
        End If
        If .Range < 0 Then
            .Font.Color = wdColorRed
        End If
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'Collapses the selection to no characters.
        .Find.Execute 'Searches again from the current selection point.
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Hi Scenography,  this solution works as well. Having 2 different working solutions helps a lot to people that are still learning to write macros like me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "-[0-9][0-9,.]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 14 Then
        If Split(.Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "specified text" Then
          .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        End If
      End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If the table might have vertically-merged cells, change:

```
If Split(.Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "specified text" Then
```

to:

```
If Split(.Tables(1).Cell(.Cells(1).RowIndex, 3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "specified text" Then
```

Comment: Hi Mac, I was trying to use your previous macros to get the result I need. This solution you posted worked once I got rid of vertically merged cells so thank you very much. Apologies if my question was too basic and if my macro was a mess. I did buy a book on the subject but I needed  a working macro before I have the opportunity to read the book. Some things look much clearer once you see the right way. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom See my updated answer for how to handle tables with vertically-merged cells.